# sufficient and necessary conditions for some sign function based on inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Given a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and a finite collection of vectors $ G \subset\mathbb{R}^n $.

are the two conditions sufficient and necessary for each other?

A: $\forall g \in G,\langle x, g \rangle >0 $

and B: $\forall S \subset G, \sum_{i\in S} \langle i, x \rangle > 0$

It's rather easy to prove $A \to B$, since $S \subset G, i \in G$ any finite sum of positive is still positive.

And I'm looking for help to prove $B \to A$.

Comment: What about the singleton subsets of $G$? Specifically, subsets of the form $\{g\}$ for $g\in G$.

Comment: right, yeah I was thinking about the same, so basically using the singleton subsets to prove $B \to A$. thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 1):

actually, the proof of $B \to A$ is also easy.

Since $\forall S \subset G$, we have a positive result.

We can construct a set $\{\{g\}|\forall g \in G\}$, which would then prove $A$